# How can I format hints for a Checkboxes control?

Tags: orbeon

I have a form with a Checkboxes control. The checkboxes have rather long hints. The width for the hint is rather narrow which doesn't work well for long hints. See screenshot below. We would also like to format the hint with ordered and unordered lists. Is there any way to accomplish this? Or would this require code changes to Orbeon?

[image]

Comment: Hints are by generally meant to be short. Long texts like this would be more appropriate for help messages but I don't think we support help in items yet. Maybe @avernet can comment more on the difficulty of changing the formatting, but that has to go hand in hand with positioning, which can be tricky.

Comment: Andrew, as mentioned by Erik, the tooltip isn't designed for such long explanatory text. Is this a real situation you've encountered? Have you, since then, found a workaround?